# Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”] using change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, selector, onchange

I have a lot of input text which contains the name: "strumento", I would check when change one of these.

```
<input name="prezzo_strumento_000000000194">
<input name="prezzo_strumento_000000000195">
```

I try use this:

```
$("input[name*=strumento]").change(function(){
    console.log("change");
});
```

but it isn't working!
Can you help me?

thank you

---

I solved, The problem is I create dynamically the inputs with javascript.

I use now to solve my problem:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name*="strumento"]', function() {
```

Comment: share your markup , also try `$("input[name*='strumento']")`

Comment: What is meaning of `key`?

Comment: `key` means `name` or `id` attribute ?

Comment: what are you trying to do be specific also share some HTML

Comment: You mentioned the input text is *containing* the key. So you're looking for the "value" attribute? `$("input[value*=strumento]")`

Comment: dear friend if you better describe what you are trying to do here properly maybe we can help

Answer (score 0):

the change event trigger after you blur.
maybe you should add the keyup

```
$("input[name*=strumento]")
.keyup(handler)
.change(handler);

function handler(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```